# Удаление сообщений с несколькими фото во вложениях

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Сделал код, который по команде `del`, удаляет сообщение. Но, если пользователь отправляет от 2-х фото (как галерея) одной публикацией, то удаляет только одно фото, а не два.

Как исправить код, чтобы бот удалял все фото одной командой?

```py
    @dp.message_handler(commands=['del'],commands_prefix="!/")
    async def message_del(message: types.Message):
        if message.content_type!=['text', 'photo', 'document', 'audio', 'video']:
            text = message.text
            if isinstance(message.caption, str):
                caption = message.caption
            else:
                caption = ''

            if hasattr(message, 'text') and isinstance(text, str):
                await message.reply(f"\n️Публикация удалена.", parse_mode="HTML")
                await message.bot.delete_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.reply_to_message.message_id)
            elif hasattr(message, 'caption') and message.media_group_id not in check_mess:
                check_mess.append(message.media_group_id)
                await message.reply(f"\n️Публикация удалена.", parse_mode="HTML")
                await message.bot.delete_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.reply_to_message.message_id)
                check_mess.clear()
                return
```

Comment: И это, ни как, не исправит? в одной же, публикации, добавляются, до 10 фото.

Comment: Перебирайте все медиафайлы в сообщении и удаляйте их по одному.

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn это не так работает, одно сообщения и есть одно фото